# How to convert multiple number to single letters to create a phrase from a book

Tags: python, numbers, ascii

I have been given the task to decode a list of numbers. The original text was taken and, letter by letter, converted into its ASCII numerical equivalent.  E.g. “T” → 84.  Each of these numerical values were encrypted by driving them through this process: **encrypted value = a X (original value) + b**. The first two integers in the file are the a and b values; the rest of the integers represent the encrypted text.

For example, your encryption might look like this:

```
 -4, -63, -355, -191, -479, -507, -511, -467, -191, -547, -507, -531, -191, -479, -451, -535, -467, -191, -475, -507, -507, -463, -191, -539, -467, -451, -527, -479, -467, -519, -191, -539, -479, -483, -495, -467, -191, -355, -191, -451, -499, -191, -475, -507, -503, -467, -247
```

Therefore, `a = -4`and `b = -63`.  Every integer after this is an encrypted letter.

To figure out what -355 equals to you will have to -> (355 - 63) / 4 = 73 
73 in the ASCII table is "I"

**Now I just have to figure out a code that will take all the numbers above and have it spit out every letter by letter till a passage is formed.**

Please help me

Comment: The idea here is that you attempt the task yourself so that you learn programming. Post your most promising attempts for this and you can get help over problems you are facing

Comment: I agrre with MohitC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = [4, 63, 355, 191, 479, 507, 511, 467, 191, 547, 507, 531, 191, 479, 451, 535, 467, 191, 475, 507, 507, 463, 191, 539, 467, 451, 527, 479, 467, 519, 191, 539, 479, 483, 495, 467, 191, 355, 191, 451, 499, 191, 475, 507, 503, 467, 247]
a, b = lst[:2]
ans = ''.join([chr((abs(val) - b)//a) for val in lst[2:]])
print(ans)
```

**Output:**

```
I hope you have good weather while I am gone.
```

Encryption:

```
enc = [(a * ord(char)) + b for char in ans]
#[355, 191, 479, 507, 511, 467, 191, 547, 507, 531, 191, 479, 451, 535, 467, 191, 475, 507, 507, 463, 191, 539, 467, 451, 527, 479, 467, 519, 191, 539, 479, 483, 495, 467, 191, 355, 191, 451, 499, 191, 475, 507, 503, 467, 247]
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot in how I had to format all the numbers and get them to output the word. but you see I have been given a page full of numbers and they are much bigger than the example given above and there are many more. Would this code also work with any number or would I have to tweak it? I can show you all the number I have to use if you want to.

Comment: it will work for any number of elements. You just have to update the list

Comment: also how would I take numbers like this : 15089, 21059, 23049, 23646, 21457, 21059, 7328, 15288, 20263, 23646, 23646, 21855, 23845, 23049 and put them in a code with the formula : (x - 960)/199  = y. X would represent the numbers above and Y would represent the numbers that I can then translate in the ASCII table. so what I am asking for do you know a code in which I can use the formula that I have above and put in a bunch of number that would spit put numbers that would be able to be used in the ASCII table for converting numbers into letters.

Comment: How to do I do that? Sorry I am a little new to this part. Where are the A, B values and what do I change about them

Comment: `a = 199 and b = 960`

Comment: I relize that a = 199 and b = b.                                                                                                 the number that I have are like this-199,-960,-15089,-21059,-23049,-23646,-21457,-21059,-7328,-15288,-20263,-23646,-23646,-21855,-23845,-23049,-22850,-7328,-22850,-23049,-24044,-21855,-20661,-21059,-20860,-7328,-24044,-21656,-21059,-7328,-21258,-22452,-20263,-23845,-21656,-21855,-22850,-21457,-7328,-23646,-21059,-20860,-7328,-22452,-21855,-21457,-21656,-24044,-7328,-23049,-22850,-7328,-24044,-21656,-21059,-7328,-21855,-22850,-23845,-24044,-23646,-24243

Comment: but hone I switch the numbers around using your line of code I get an error

Comment: Why the values are negative?

Comment: ignore that, they are positive. but when I switch out the number I have provided in example in the original question. with the number from my recent comment it gives me and error.

Comment: you need to use same a and b for encryption and decryption

Comment: thanks man I finally got it. thank you so much for the help. I was stuck on this for the last three days!